# Optimising a large SELECT/JOIN query with millions of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I have the following query for MySQL 5.7 which no matter what I do with it is running at roughly a minute which I am trying to get to run faster (preferably get performance down to seconds). The rough amount of data in these tables is 2 million for actions, 90k for sessions and 100k for profiles.

```
select 
    a.id as `action_id`,
    a.type as `event_type`,
    p.ip_address as `ip_address`,
    p.browser_string as `browser_string`,
    p.ua_device_type,
    p.ua_os_family,
    p.ua_os_name,
    p.ua_type,
    p.ua_family,
    p.ua_version,
    p.ipuas_hash,
    s.session_string,
    s.traffic_source,
    s.org_traffic_source,
    a.datetime as `timestamp`
from is_action as a
join is_session as s on a.session_id=s.id
join is_profile as p on s.profile_id=p.id
```

which is using the following tables (removed some fields that aren't relevant):

```
CREATE TABLE `is_profile` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ip_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`browser_string` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`ua_device_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ua_os_family` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ua_os_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ua_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ua_family` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ua_version` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ipuas_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`session_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
KEY `ua_type` (`ua_type`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `is_session` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`traffic_source` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`session_string` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`session_length` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`org_traffic_source` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`org_page` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`action_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE KEY `comp_profile` (`profile_id`,`id`) USING BTREE,
KEY `profile_id` (`profile_id`) USING BTREE,
KEY `datetime` (`datetime`) USING BTREE,
KEY `traffic_source` (`traffic_source`) USING BTREE,
KEY `session_length` (`session_length`) USING BTREE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_profile` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `is_profile` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `is_action` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`session_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`details` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
`weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE KEY `comp_session` (`session_id`,`id`) USING BTREE,
KEY `session_id` (`session_id`) USING BTREE,
KEY `datetime` (`datetime`) USING BTREE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_session` FOREIGN KEY (`session_id`) REFERENCES `is_session` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I've tried different types of joins, forcing indexes and adding more indexes on relevant fields and have even increased the RAM and CPU on the database, but nothing seems to cut down the query-time. I've also included a screenshot of the `EXPLAIN` below (the blocked out parts are sensitive info).

[image: Query Explain]

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: ** Added foreign key relationships between the tables and added the `EXPLAIN` image I forgot to add.

Comment: I don't have an answer, only an observation - we all learned normalization, the stability of it, the consistency of it. But when data gets big, we have to step back and build our tables to match our queries, and tiptoe into the fraught realm where our code must ensure the consistency of our data.

Comment: This data is not “big” even if the database is running on a (reasonably modern) PC. Assuming it is running on a properly specified server than it should handle tables containing 10s, or even 100s, of millions of rows without any difficulty

Comment: An observation: in InnoDB, I think I'm right in saying that any AI id is automatically silently added to the end of all indexes, so `comp_profile (profile_id,id),KEY profile_id` is the same as `KEY profile_id`.

Comment: You are returning zillions of rows with lots of columns.  That is going to take time.

Comment: @JSBach - Not quite.  See my "answer".

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How big are the tables?

Answer (score 0):

You need foreign key constraints defined on the FKs you are using in your joins.

You seem to have forgotten to include the EXPLAIN PLAN.

BTW your unique constraints are not achieving much as they include the PKs which are, by definition, unique already

Comment: Whoops, forgot to attach the image. I have added the foreign keys to the table and attached the explain as you requested.

Comment: Just to be clear, did the FKs already exist but you hadn’t included them in your question or have you just added them to your tables? If you've added them then what difference has that made to the query execution?

Comment: Just added them and they didn't seem to make too much of a difference.

Comment: Ok - in which case the limitation is the specification of the platform that you are running the query on and you're not going to get it to run faster. As it is a simple query with no filtering, the only thing that could be tuned is the joins and as you have FKs defined on them there is nothing else you can tune.

Comment: You don't *need* fk constraints

Comment: @NickW - No.  The `EXPLAIN` shows that there are adequate `INDEXes`.  `FOREIGN KEYs` assure that such indexes are built, but do not otherwise provide any speed improvement.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an Answer but a lengthy response to JSBach.)

This is a strange combination

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE KEY `comp_session` (`session_id`,`id`) USING BTREE,
KEY `session_id` (`session_id`) USING BTREE,
```

If you intended `session_id` to be unique, you failed.  To make it unique:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE KEY `comp_session` (`session_id`) USING BTREE,
-- redundant: KEY `session_id` (`session_id`) USING BTREE,
```

At which point, why not promote `session_id` to be the PK?

Back to UNIQUE (`session_id`,`id`) -- Since `id` is already declared UNIQUE`because of the PK, this declaration provides _no_ useful uniqueness constraint.  If it is primarily designed to be`KEY(session_id, id)`, then it is redundant with` KEY(session_id)`; get rid of one or the other.

`PRIMARY KEY`:

- Uniquely identifies each row
- Declares the column (or combination of columns) to be UNIQUE
- Is an index

`UNIQUE`:

- Declares the column (or combination of columns) to be UNIQUE
- Is an index

`FOREIGN KEY`:

- Declares an index if not already present
- Provide an integrity constraint that alerts you when you insert a row for which there is not a corresponding row in another table
- Optionally provides "cascading" actions

(For the OP's Question about speed, see Gordon's Comment.)